# Rails 3 better routing

Tags: routes, ruby-on-rails-3

Out of curiosity.
In the docs of rails3 they say that as rule of thumb, I shouldn't nest more than one level of resources. Is there any better way to do that then?

```
  scope "(:locale)", :locale => /pl/ do

    resources :users  

    namespace "admin" do
      resources :universities do
        resources :faculties
      end
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 2):

Why? You're not nesting more than one level of resources :-)

Comment: Well, ok then, then let's suppose that I have news for each faculty ;-)

Comment: @Warden: I've been using nested resources up to three levels deep quite happily for years so I shouldn't worry about it too much. Especially also as it appears you're going this in a /admin area. Remember there's the :shallow option if you find the url helpers get unwieldy. The difficulty that most often arises for me is when I need to access a resource in a nested fashion and directly. Controllers can tend to get verbose when dealing with this.