# How to properly avoid nesting routes more than 1 level deep in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, nested-routes

I'm having a hard time conceptualizing the best way to set up the resources for this project.

Here are my current routes:

```
resources :customers do
  resources :jobs
end

resources :jobs
  resources :rooms
  resources :memos
  resources :appliances
  resources :accessories
end
```

I took my structure from this question:  [Rails 3 routing: Avoiding Deep Nesting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6345314/rails-3-routing-avoiding-deep-nesting)

My question(s) are as follows:

1. Am I doing this right?
2. If yes, what does this accomplish that nesting more than 1 level deep does not?  I'm assuming it's just absolute paths for things like jobs/rooms/id, instead of customers/jobs/rooms/id - but I don't know if this is correct.

Any further education will be appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: there is nothing wrong. go for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Yes, you are doing it right. You could either nest the resources or not, it is up to you.
2. Nesting one more level usually "forces" you to find each resource.

Consider these routes:

```
resources :customers do
  resources :jobs do
    resources :rooms
  end
end
```

Then you would have relative paths like `/customers/1/jobs/2/rooms/3/show`.This implies that the Room #3 belongs to Job #2 which belong to Customer #1.

In other words, you would end up for the `show` action of the `RoomsController` with 3 instances: `@customer`, `@job` and `@room`, all **set by a SQL query**.

But you already defined that a `room` belongs to a `job` and that a `job` belong to a `room`. So **do you really have to run 3 SQL queries?** No, which is why you avoid deeply nested routes (over 2~3 levels).

Comment: Perfect - that makes a lot more sense when it's explained in terms of SQL queries!

Comment: @MrYoshi could you take a look at this issue? It's almost the same, but I can't figure it out. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35672666/rails-structuring-routes-controller-views-for-nested-resources